# Old Chicago-based cartoon short from the 60's

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I remember a silent cartoon short featuring two young alien children.  Martians, I think.  In the cartoon they interact just as my sister & I would, up before our folks watching TV on a Saturday morning.  In one scene a drink shaker is involved & one of the kids get shaken up inside, only later to be spilled out & re-assembled.  Would love to get to see it again after 50 some-odd years.  Was in the Chicago area, probably WGN, back in the 60's.  Anyone?